# Passing PHP Session Variable to 'Include' Page Issue

Tags: php, session-variables, mysql-insert-id

I'm working with a main PHP page that has four included templates:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<title>Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include ("script/select.class.php"); ?>
<div class="content">
<?php 
    include("./templates/one.php");
    include("./templates/two.php");
    include("./templates/three.php");
    include("./templates/four.php");
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

'two.php' contains a form (the_form) submitted via AJAX:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "script/add_new.php",
            data: $("#the_form").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                newID = data;
                alert(newID); 
            }
        });
});
```

On 'add_new.php', once the INSERT is completed, I have this PHP code:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$_SESSION['new_id'] = mysqli_insert_id($con);

echo $_SESSION['new_id'];
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that even though $_SESSION['new_id'] will pass back through the Ajax 'data' var and show up in the 'alert', I get an **Unidentified Index** error if I attempt to display on the next tempate page (three.php) using `<?php echo $_SESSION['new_id'] ?>`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `$_SESSION['new_id']` is set during the AJAX request, while `include("./templates/three.php");` is included BEFORE the js code of the ajax part and html are sent to the browser, before any ajax request and so on.

Comment: Ultimately I want the value to be stored in the session var. The 'alert' is being used to prove that the session var exists. Are you saying that the session var is unavailable to me because 'three.php' has already been included?

Comment: At the moment when `three.php` is included you, probably, do not have this variable set or it is not set to the value you are expecting. You php code 'creates' html code with js code for ajax request, outputs it to browser, browser makes ajax request to another php code, and this happens AFTER the `include("./templates/three.php");` If you are trying to show something later with single request to `three.php` which has only `<?php echo $_SESSION['new_id'] ?>` in it - you have to start session in this single file.

Comment: just make sure you have `session_start();` in `add_new.php`

Comment: Thank you, Cheery. I'll need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheery is correct. I'll need to take a different approach.